# respond_with json oddness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
 respond_to :json

  def create
    respond_with('test')
  end
```

I was just doing some testing and the above gives me an error of:

undefined method `test_url' for #

Why is it trying to turn test into a url? Is this a bug?

Comment: do you have any other declarations in your controller involving test_url? also, 'test' isn't exactly an object or a json object...you might want to try respond_with({"test" : 'test'}) or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JSON object must have two octets, as in a key and a value. You can't just send through a string.

Try this instead:

```
respond_with(:message => "test")
```

Comment: I may be mistaken but I don't believe the word "octets" is being used correctly in this context: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error (respond_with threw an undefined method `test_url' error) when test was a class and my routes didn't contain a resource entry.

```
respond_to :json

def method
  if request.post?
    @test = Test.create
    respond_with @test
  end
  ...
end
```

Adding a resource entry to my routes.rb fixed the problem

```
resources :test
```

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. You shouldn't need to define all of the routes to return the resource.